# Exporting json data outside of fetch scope

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a simple example that fetches data from an api.

```
fetch("https://api.example.com/results")
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then(function(data) {
            console.log(data)
});
```

Now, I'd have the data on my web page, but I want to 'export' the data to outside of fetch so i can use to filter data based on a form. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Can you explain more about the filtering process? Does the form data change based on change events from the user, for example?

Comment: you can pass the data to a function outside of fetch

Comment: Yes, the data changes based on change events,like show 50,100 results per page, and sort data in an alphabetic order.

Comment: how would I do that, @zabusa? I've been trying but no luck.

Comment: create a function outside the fetch and call it inside then data returns

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by zabusa, you could create a function that performs the filtering, then call that function from within the fetch's `.then` chain:

```js
function filter(data) {
    console.log("Filtering based on " + JSON.stringify(data))
    // add the rest of your filtering code here
}

fetch("https://reqres.in/api/users/2")
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then(function(data) {
        filter(data)
});
```

You may also want to consider using `await`, like so:

```
var response = await fetch("https://reqres.in/api/users/2")
var data = await response.json()
filter(data)
```

or even:

```
filter(await (await fetch("https://reqres.in/api/users/2")).json())
```